# Does Pydantic accept the same query with both single and multi values?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

My schema:

```
class ArticleBase(Schema):
    page: Optional[int] = 1
    topic: Optional[List[str]] = Query(None)
```

Router:

```
@api.get("/articles/", tags = ['Articles'])
def article_list(request, article: ArticleBase = Query(...)):
    return article
```

I want Pydantic/FastAPI to accept query with both single and multiple values.

I want both of them to get accepted:

```
www.example.com/articles/?topic=hello&topic=world
www.example.com/articles/?topic=hello
```

How can I achieve it?

The error message I am getting:

```
"msg": "value is not a valid list",
"type": "type_error.list"
```

Comment: Not super sure about this one but I'd try setting `topic`'s default value to None instead of Query(None).

Comment: @igotinfected, thanks for your comment. It didn't work. The interesting part is that writing a list of values doesn't get accepted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing `Optional` from my code I managed it to work as I wanted. It accepts query with both single and multiple values.

My working code:

```
class ArticleBase(Schema):
    page: Optional[int] = 1
    topic: List[str] = Query(None)
```

Didn't understand why that was the reason. Maybe I'm missing something from documentation but read it carefully and didn't find anything related to it.